# Refactoring/Renaming Variable in Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring

I'm writing a little Android App and things are working out nicely, actually. The only problem I'm facing is that Android Studio won't let me refactor all of the occurrences of the variable I inted to rename (see: attached link).

I'm simply using the Alt-Shift-R Shortcut, entering the wanted text and pressing enter. The field variable is changed - but its occurences (though highlighted before) aren't. Using the preview window doesn't change the outcome.

Am I missing anything? I feel like a moron. :')

[Variable naming after hitting Enter-Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQHbV.png)

- valueAusgabe is the previous naming

Comment: R-click -->  Refactor --> Rename (shortcut is also shown - based on OS)

Comment: Like I said, I am able to trigger the renaming shortcut/can enter a new name and Android Studio even shows all occurences of the to-be-changed renaming. Upon pressing enter it just changes the field variable but not all occurences (see attached picture).

Comment: You didn't specify OS, so I was confirming you were using right shortcut from manually selecting (shortcuts change depending on OS, preferences etc.., so on a Mac, for instance by default, Alt-Shift-R is meaningless).

Answer (score 14):

If you're on Windows or Linux you should be able to rename all occurrences of your variable (variableAusgabe) by just using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> shortcut.

When you use this, a pop-up shows up and you have to enter the text you want to replace (variableAusgabe), and the text you want to replace it with. Select Refactor for each occurrence or Replace All.

Answer (score 13):

In Android Studio (ver.3.1) shortcut for Refactor/Rename is: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

> ctrl + R in windows,
>   it works for me

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem a few days back, just go ahead to refactor the variable and when the popup appears to confirm the refactoring the variable just uncheck the "Search in comments and strings", and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some software running in the background that catches the event and isn't firing it back at the system for other software to process it.

One example, and a very popular one, is **GeForce Experience In-Game Overlay (Shadowplay)**. Shift+F6 is used by it to switch post-processing filter slots.

If you happen to run a device with an nvidia chip, you probably have it running.

**Steps to find and fix the issue:**

1. Open its settings:

- Alt+Z by default, or
- RMB click its icon in the tray -> GF Experience -> Gear icon in the upper-right corner -> Scroll down to In-Game Overlay -> Press the Settings button.

2. Click the Gear icon on the right.
3. Keyboard shortcuts.
4. Find Shift+F6, click, press Delete on your keyboard.

If that software is not running in the background, it may be something else but equally as "greedy" is running then. Look for it in the tray. Good luck!